# unexpected TypeError with ipython

Tags: python, ipython, typeerror

Yesterday I did the following program and it was running **without any error** in the Spyder IDE for Windows with **IPython Interpreter**. But today I don't know what happened it showing me an error. So, I also tried this in the Spyder IDE for Ubuntu but it shows the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 487, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\BK\.spyder2\.temp.py", line 23, in <module>
    print sum_prime(2000000)
  File "C:\Users\BK\.spyder2\.temp.py", line 21, in sum_prime
    return sum(suspected) + sum_p
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'int'
```

**Program:**

```
import math

def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2: return False
    if num == 2: return True
    if num % 2 == 0: return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1, 2):
        if num % i == 0: return False
    return True

def sum_prime(num):
    if num < 2: return 0
    sum_p = 2
    core_primes = []
    suspected = set(range(3, num + 1, 2))
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1, 2):
        if is_prime(i): core_primes.append(i)
    for p in core_primes:
        sum_p += p
        suspected.difference_update(set(range(p, num + 1, p)))
    return sum(suspected) + sum_p

print sum_prime(2000000)
```

But it executes **successfully** when I execute this in **dedicated python interpreter** or **external system terminal**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `numpy.core.fromnumeric.sum` not the python builtin function (IPython is importing it behind the scenes):

```
In [1]: sum
Out[1]: <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.sum>

In [2]: sum({1,2,3,4})
Out[2]: set([1, 2, 3, 4])  # returns a set

In [3]: del sum

In [4]: sum({1,2,3,4})
Out[4]: 10
```

---

You can fix this by making sure you are using the *"right sum"* :

```
import __builtin__
sum = __builtin__.sum
```

Comment: Spyder IDE `Run` > `Configure...` > then I selected `Execute in current Python or Ipython interpreter`

Comment: I executed only that line and it says `numpy.core.fromnumeric`

Comment: So, why there is name collusion

Comment: how to access built in sum()

Comment: Just now I added `del sum` to the begining of the program like as you said and it works in IPython but not in dedicated python interpreter it says `NameError: name 'sum' is not defined` :'(

Comment: I added `sum = sum = __builtin__.sum` `NameError: name '__builtin__' is not defined`

Comment: and I am using python 2.7.3

Comment: Is there any common way for both the interpreters